# Need help understanding how to build multiple RPMs

Tags: rpmbuild

I've been trying to understand how to build a simple RPM.

I have the following repository https://github.com/integralist/simple-rpm which includes the relevant SPEC file and it works fine in generating an RPM from within a Docker container.

But the issue I have is understanding how to build multiple RPMs considering I was pretty much forced to use a single `~/rpmbuild` directory to house the files.

Originally I created a test RPM directory structure within `~/testing-rpmbuild` and when I ran the `rpmbuild` command it automatically created `~/rpmbuild` for me and then started to fail as my spec file (which was in `~/testing-rpmbuild`) had referenced other files which couldn't be found because the OS seemed to expect it to be inside `~/rpmbuild` instead (which was empty because at that point I didn't realise the OS had automatically created the `~/rpmbuild` directory).

So in the end I just moved all my files from `~/testing-rpmbuild` to `~/rpmbuild` and everything worked fine. But I'm not sure how you're expected to build multiple different RPMs when you're restricted to a single `~/rpmbuild` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you would use `mock` to run your build inside a clean environment that would also pull down and install the build dependencies leaving your host machine alone so you'd have a clean build directory and wouldn't be building the same RPM multiple times in the same mock session.

[Source](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-anywhere-different-build-area.html)

The difference here is you're using Docker which is providing some of the same benefits of mock (An isolated build environment) but doesn't provide the automatic package installation based on the build dependencies.

You could parse the spec file and install the dependencies at runtime, then move onto building the RPM.

`rpmbuild` targets the `~/rpmbuild` by default and you shouldn't need to change into another directory as you're building one package when you run the container.

It might make more sense to mount your current work directory as a volume then build based off that, for example:

`FROM fedora:latest
RUN yum -y install tree man man-pages make gcc rpm-build
WORKDIR $HOME/rpmbuild
ENTRYPOINT ["rpmbuild"]
CMD ["-bb", "-v", "SPECS/*.spec"]`

then to build the RPM run the following:

`docker run -v $(pwd):/root/rpmbuild integralist/simplerpm`

and you should have the RPM in `RPMS/*` in the current directory of the project you ran the command from.

Also, you can change the build directory using `~/.rpmrc` with the following:

`topdir: /alternate/build/path`

or specifying `--buildroot` when building the rpm.

[Source](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-anywhere-different-build-area.html)